How to set "customWorkspace" with an enviroment variable in Jenkins
I have a project that runs a some stages of the build parallelly in multiple nodes where I would like to assign custom workspace paths for each node using an environment variable set in each of the agent PCs.
I want to build them in different paths for each agent and I'd like not to keep the paths inside the pipeline script.
Briefly, I want to achieve something like this:
agent {
    node {
        label "agent 1 label"
        customWorkspace env.agent_1_workspace
    }
}

(agent_1_workspace is the environment variable set in the agent PC)
I tried this and it didn't work (I can understand why) but, is there a way I could achieve this?

This is not possible to achieve using the declarative node directive, but you can easily implement it by extracting the path from the environment value with a shell (sh) step and then use the Allocate Workspace (ws) pipeline step to run your logic in a custom workspace.
It can look something like:
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "agent 1 label"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Custom Workspace') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Get the workspace path from the environment variable on the agent
                    def path = sh(script:"printenv agent_1_workspace", returnStdout:true).trim()

                    // Run the rest pf the steps in the custom workspace
                    ws(path) {
                        // All logig that is executed here runs inside the custom workspace
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Or if you don't want (or don't need) to use the script block you can do it in a single line:
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "agent 1 label"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Custom Workspace') {
            steps {
                ws(sh(script:"printenv agent_1_workspace", returnStdout:true).trim()) {
                    // All code that is executed here runs inside the custom workspace
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

